# is the order of the fields important when writing to a sheet?

Tags: json, rest, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to write to a google sheet using rest.

I have generated the following json:

```
{
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
"values": [
  [
     "foo",
     "foo",
     "foo",
     "foo"
  ],
  [
     "foo",
     "foo",
     "foo",
     "foo"
  ]
 ],
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:D5"
 }
```

as stated here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing the order is "range","majorDimension" and "values". Is the order important or will it work even if the order is different ?

Comment: The order should be from a higher cell to a lower cell. What I mean by high is that A1 is the highest cell. A is the highest letter, 1 is the highest number. The notation has to be A1:D5 . It can't be D5:A1.

Comment: thanks for your comment full of sense! I meant actually the order of "majorDimension","values", and "range". is this order important ?

Comment: Did it output an error when you tried in a different order ? If not, then it means that the order does not matter.

Comment: I did not try to load it yet, actually the system I am generating the json from cannot handle another order (long story) so I just wanted to know whether it's worth the effort. But I will try and post the result here. thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is : no. You can put majorDimension, values and range in the order that you want.

As Marios Karamanis stated the order of the range definition is important.